# Is there a reference for these types of cubic identities?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

I'm looking at the following generalizations for sums of two cubes.
$u^3+v^3=(u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2).$

$u^3+(u+r)^3+v^3+(v+r)^3=(u+v+r)(2u^2-2uv+2v^2+ru+rv+2r^2).$

$u^3+(u+q)^3+(u+r)^3+(u+q+r)^3+v^3+(v+q)^3+(v+r)^3+(v+q+r)^3 = \\2(u+v+q+r)(2u^2-2uv+2v^2+qu+qv+ru+rv+2q^2+2r^2+qr).$

$u^3+(u+p)^3+(u+q)^3+(u+r)^3+(u+p+q)^3+(u+p+r)^3+(u+q+r)^3+(u+p+q+r)^3\\+v^3+(v+p)^3+(v+q)^3+(v+r)^3+(v+p+q)^3+(v+p+r)^3+(v+q+r)^3+(v+p+q+r)^3 = \\4(u+v+p+q+r)(2u^2-2uv+2v^2+pu+pv+qu+qv+ru+rv+2p^2+2q^2+2r^2+pq+pr+qr).$

These identities do generalize in this direction. It seems to me that identities this natural should be known or at least talked about. Is there any known literature that discusses these identities and the generalization in any detail?

Comment: I think what you have is this:  if a polynomial  in $n$  variables  is always zero when $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r$  is zero, then the polynomial is divisible by  $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r$

Answer (score 6):

Define
$$ f(u, v) := u^3 + v^3 = (u+v)g(u, v),\quad g(u, v) := (u^2 -uv +v^2). $$
That is your first identity.

Note that if $\,z := u + v + r\,$ then $\, z = u+(v+r) = (u+r)+v.\,$ Thus,
$$ f(u, v+r) + f(u+r, v) = u^3 + (v+r)^3 + (u+r)^3 + v^3 = \\
  z\,g(u, v+r) + z\,g(u+r, v) = (u+r+v)(g(u, v+r) + g(u+r, v)). $$
That is your second identity.

Note that if $\,z := u + v + q + r\,$ then your third identity also has a
factor of $\,z\,$ on the right side for similar reasons. This generalizes
as you mentioned in your question. You asked:

> It seems to me that identities this natural should be known or at least talked about. Is there any known literature that discusses these identities and the generalization in any detail?

Natural is a matter of opinion, but these identities (except the first with
a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_cubes))
seem to have very limited application. This is probably why I think that
there is very little literature references. On the positive side, your
family of identities seems new, interesting and special. On that basis
I have included your second identity as $\texttt{id3_5_2_3c}$ in my list
of "Special Algebraic Identities" at my CSU home page.

Comment: Where and what is your list of special algebraic identities?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I had no idea you were such a great mathematician until I found your wiki and learned of somos sequences - very nice!